# How to calculate Kafka Consumer Lag Given a Single Topic and a Single Partition

Tags: apache-kafka, command-line

Is there an easy way to compute the consumer lag of a consumer for a specified Kafka Topic and partition number? I only want the integer, **nothing else**.

I know that `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my-group` will give me ALL the partitions and their lags for a single consumer group. I just want a single number output given the consumer group, a topic, and partition number. For example, if my output from the above command is

| TOPIC | PARTITION | CURRENT-OFFSET | LOG-END-OFFSET | **LAG** | CONSUMER-ID | HOST | CLIENT-ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| t1 | 2 | random num. | random num. | 34 | ... | ... | ... |
| t1 | 0 | random num. | random num. | 86 | ... | ... | ... |
| t1 | 1 | random num. | random num. | 12 | ... | ... | ... |
| t2 | 0 | random num. | random num. | 54 | ... | ... | ... |

and I want the consumer lag from topic `t1` in partition `1`, is there a command that looks at this information and only outputs `12`?

I've looked at the Kafka documentation https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html but I can't seem to find anything that works. Do I need to do some grep magic or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natively, no.

You could simply pipe the output to grep and awk, or you could use a different tool like Burrow, or Kafka lag exporter for Prometheus